# C socket programming under windows

Tags: c, sockets

Hi I'm new to socket programming and I'm trying out the following code from the tutorial of http://www.binarytides.com/winsock-socket-programming-tutorial/

I'm trying to connect to server and I'm using the IP address of google. Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in server;

    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialised.\n");

    //Create a socket
    if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    }

    printf("Socket created.\n");


    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("74.125.224.72");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(80);

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("connect error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected");

    return 0;
}
```

So far socket can be created but I can't connect to the server. To be more specific I always exit and have following:

The program '[2060] SocketCTest.exe: Native' has exited with code 1 (0x1).

even if I set a breakpoint before returns.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741580%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Don't forget to `closesocket(s);` and `WSACleanup();` before each `return` statement.

Comment: Try zeroing out "server" before initializing it (like memset(&server, 0, sizeof server)).

Comment: Exit if the call to `socket` fails. As it is, "Socket created." will be printed whether the socket was created or not. Also, when any socket call fails, you should log the code returned by `WSAGetLastError` so you know what the error was. The failure in `connect` could be something simple like a timeout; your output would give no indication.

Comment: @craig65535 already done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no error. I've tried on my computer and connect returned with error (`WSAETIMEDOUT`). I'm not sure whether there are the network settings on my computer, proxies, firewalls, and so on; or that google host is configured not to accept direct socket connections.

Anyway here's your code with some small adjustments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char c = 0;

    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d.\nPress a key to exit...", WSAGetLastError());
        c = getch();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialised.\n");

    //Create a socket
    if((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket : %d.\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        c = getch();
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Socket created. Connecting...\n");
    memset(&server, 0, sizeof server);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("74.125.224.72");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(80);

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        printf("Connect error:%d.\nPress a key to exit...", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
        c = getch();
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Connected.\nPress a key to exit...");
    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
    c = getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Now if you want to see the code actually connecting i'd suggest using `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`) instead of `74.125.224.72`, and the port `3389` for example (it's the *Remote Desktop Server (RDP)* port, if you have *RDP* configured and running on your computer) instead of `80`; or you could let `80` if you have a web server (*IIS*?) running on your computer.

To get a list of server programs that run on your computer run the command:

```
`netstat -an | findstr LISTEN`
```

which would output a bunch of lines (and the ones that we care about are) in this form (here's the one corresponding to the *RDP* example from above):

```
`TCP    127.0.0.1:3389         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING`
```

Comment: Hi CristiFati, I tried your code and changed the IP address to 127.0.0.1 and port number to 3389 but it shows: The program '[3468] SocketCTest.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: After this I tried several other addresses and ports from my list of server programs and still get the same result.

Comment: I'm using intranet of my company so do you think that might cause the problem?

Comment: Yes that's the reason. Because when i placed the solution I was at the office and i couldn't connect to that host, but right now from home i can. Most likely _Google_ is available from the browser at my office because i have a _http proxy_ defined and browsers use that, while this program tries to connect directly.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try later when I get home.

Comment: Hey CristiFati, when you were trying it at work, were you having problem  even when connecting to local host? In realized I can't log in to my work computer at home so I didn't try it home. I assume I should be able to connect to local as it doesn't require internet. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: You should always be able to connect to `localhost`. You just have to pick the right port (some server app to be listening on that port).

Comment: The problem is that I can't.... I just use your code above and change the IP address and port number to ones I got on my laptop. I got: 10.30.215.187:139, so I changed IP to 10.30.215.187 and port to 139

Comment: I added system pause and found that they are actually connected... It just exit before I could see the connected line

Comment: I added some functionality so that the code waits for user input before exiting. Also applied @Stuart's suggestion.

Comment: Does this whole thing answer to your question?